# AngularJS,$scope in run

Tags: angularjs, scope

I am new to `AngularJS`.

Actually I am having a functionality which is common to all controllers, so I kept that piece of code in run method. That code specifies to navigate to other page when a condition get satisfied, but there my `$location.path()` is not working so I kept `$scope.$apply` after that it made me to navigate... (this is working when I kept it in controller).

But when I put it in run its throwing error about `$scope` (but without $scope no navigation is there).

```
 if(prevPath=='/menupage')
        {

                $location.path('/restaurant');
                $scope.$apply() ;
                    }

        else if(prevPath=='/restaurant')
        {

                $location.path('/login');
        $scope.$apply() ;

        }

        else if(prevPath=='/menucategory')
        {

                $location.path('/menupage');
        $scope.$apply() ;       
        }

        else if(prevPath=='/menucategorylist')
        {

                $location.path('/menucategory');
        $scope.$apply() ;
        }

        else if(prevPath=='/shoppingcart')
        {

                $location.path('/menucategory');
            $scope.$apply() ;
        }

        else (prevPath=='/item')
        {

                $location.path('/menucategory');
        $scope.$apply() ;

        }
```

I think that there is no option except putting the code in run... But `$scope` not working.

Is there any other method like putting  that code in a function and calling from run
(can we call a method which is in sevice from run)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$route.reload();`

instead of `$scope.$spply();`

see

```
if(prevPath=='/menupage')
        {

                $location.path('/restaurant');
                $route.reload();
                    }
.
.
.
```

> And must specify the `$route` in globally